# Angular multiple directives error on md-datepicker

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material, isolate-scope

I'm making a dinamic list of dates. The user can adds all [datepickers](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker) he wants, but I have to validate that there are not matching dates, all of them have to be different, that's the only requisite.

I've made a custom directive validation and it's triggered correctly, but when I try to use its isolate scope, I just get that error (Multiple directives). Other questions/solutions that I've seen here, propose to delete the isolate scope, but I need it to pass to the directive the array of dates and to be able to compare them with the current selected.

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/Drumnbass/pen/XdQOMX?editors=1010) that reproduces the problem. If you remove the `noMatchingDates` directive's `scope`, the error just disappears and you can see and add datepickers properly. I mean this `scope`:

```
scope: {
  getAllDates: "&allDates"
}
```

I think that it has to do with this line in [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir?p0=mdDatepicker&p1=%20(module:%20material.components.datepicker)&p2=noMatchingDates&p3=%20(module:%20MyApp)&p4=new%2Fisolated):

> Multiple directives requesting isolated scope.

And it probably also has to do with the md-datepicker which would have more directives using the isolate scope. So, how can I solve this error (and still being able to send the dates list)?

If it can't be solved (keeping the scope) given the nature of the [md-datepicker](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdDatepicker), how can I reach this dynamyc validation? I think it could be done using a controller and the `ng-change`, but I'm not sure if it would be a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there is no reason for your directive to require an isolated scope. Use isolated scope when your directive is like a reusable "visual component". Your directive is about logic validation and shouldn't prevent another such component.

To fix your problem, you can remove the isolated scope and use your directive in the HTML this way:

```
<div ... no-matching-dates="overtimeList">
```

Then in your link function, you can retrieve the value of that attribute this way:

```
var dates = scope.$parse(attr.noMatchingDates);
```

This will give you the content of what is bound to `no-matching-dates`, so in this case it will return `overtimeList`.

I have never used the `ctrl.$parsers.unshift` syntax, but it seems that you can also use it to retrieve that value. Simply remove the `scope.$parse` line that I just gave you and write:

```
ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(arrayOfDates) { ... })
```

This should work as well. Note that in the first approach you need to `$watch` for changes if you want to run the validation every time.

Comment: Thanks, I think it works, but anyway I still have a problem with this. Passing the array of dates through `no-matching-dates`, it only gives me dates until the current date being modified. For example, if I have 5 datepickers and I'm modifying the 3rd, I just get the three first dates and the rest (2) are missing... in the same way, if I'm modifying the 4th date, I just get the 4 first dates and the last one is missing... :(

Comment: Btw @floribon, where and how should I `$watch` for changes?

Comment: you can use `scope.$watch(attr.noMatchingDates)` to watch for changes of references on  `overtimeList`. Or if that's an array that will get updated on place you can use `$watchCollection`. Unfortunately your use case and questions are a bit too wide, you should write a small example of your problem and ask a new question about any specific point.